# I can't figure out what is wrong with my "copies" variable

Tags: oop, copy-constructor

I can't figure out what is wrong with my "copies" variable.

This is a demo code for my home work which show us basic syntax and how to use different types of OOP constructors and keywords. The question when is run this everything runs fine but the problem is in the copies variable it should have a value of 1 when the constructor is copied but it doesn't seem to work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
const int JANE_HOURS = 30, JIM_HOURS = 20, SETTER_HOURS = 40;
const double SETTER_DAYS = 3.0, HOURS_PER_DAY = 24.0;
class WorkerHours {
    private:
        int hoursWorked;
        int copies;
    public:
        void setData(int);
        void setData(double);
        int getCpy();
        WorkerHours();
        WorkerHours(int);
        WorkerHours operator + (const WorkerHours &combinedOb) const;
        WorkerHours operator += (const WorkerHours &combinedOb);
        operator int() const;
        operator double() const;
        friend void showInternalData(string label, const WorkerHours &worker);
        WorkerHours(WorkerHours &janeCpy);
        ~WorkerHours();
 };



WorkerHours::WorkerHours() {
    hoursWorked = 0;
    copies = 0;
}
WorkerHours::WorkerHours(int hoursWork) {
    hoursWorked = hoursWork;
}
WorkerHours::WorkerHours(WorkerHours &janeCpy) {
    hoursWorked = janeCpy.hoursWorked;
    copies = (janeCpy.copies + 1);
}
int WorkerHours::getCpy() {
    return copies;
}
WorkerHours WorkerHours::operator += (const WorkerHours &combinedOb) {
    WorkerHours result;
    hoursWorked += combinedOb.hoursWorked;
    return result;
}
WorkerHours WorkerHours::operator + (const WorkerHours &combinedOb) const {
    WorkerHours result;
    result.hoursWorked = hoursWorked + combinedOb.hoursWorked;
    return result;
}
void WorkerHours::setData(int a) {
    hoursWorked = a;
}
void WorkerHours::setData(double a) {
    hoursWorked = a * HOURS_PER_DAY;
}
WorkerHours::operator int() const {
    return hoursWorked;
}
WorkerHours::operator double() const {
    return (hoursWorked / HOURS_PER_DAY);
}
WorkerHours::~WorkerHours() {
    cout << "Destroyed" << endl;
}

// This is the prototype of the showInternalData function.
// It must access INTERNAL STRUCTURES in the worker object.
// Do NOT use member functions to get the data for that object.
void showInternalData(string label,  WorkerHours &worker);
int main()
{
    // Conversion constructor
    WorkerHours jane = JANE_HOURS, jim = JIM_HOURS;
    // Copy constructor
    WorkerHours janeCopy = jane;
    // + operator
    WorkerHours combined = jane + jim;
    // Default constructor
    WorkerHours testSetters;
    // Variables set aside for calculations
    double daysWorked;
    int hoursWorked;
    // You can use static_cast here, but it shouldn't be required.
    //static_cast<double>(combined);
    // Type conversion operator - int
    daysWorked = combined;
    cout << "TEST DAYS WORKED : " << daysWorked << endl;
    // You can use static_cast here, but it shouldn't be required.
    // static_cast<int>(combined);
    // Type conversion operator - double
    hoursWorked = combined; //using the = already (over loading)
    cout << "TEST HOURS WORKED: " << hoursWorked << endl;
    // Now we start using the internal function
    showInternalData("Jane", jane);
    showInternalData("JaneCopy", janeCopy);
    showInternalData("Jim", jim);
    showInternalData("Combined", combined);
    // += operators
    jane += janeCopy;
    showInternalData("Jane + JaneCopy", jane);
    // Now we test the overloaded setters
    testSetters.setData(SETTER_HOURS);
    showInternalData("Testing int setter", testSetters);
    testSetters.setData(SETTER_DAYS);
    showInternalData("Testing double setter", testSetters);
    // We’re done
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


void showInternalData(string label, WorkerHours &worker) {
    string x = label;
    cout << "Data: " << x << ", " << "Hours worked:" <<  worker.operator int() << ", " << "Copy generation: "<< worker.getCpy()<< endl;
}
```

---

This what the output should look like:

```
TEST DAYS WORKED : 2.08333
TEST HOURS WORKED: 50
Data: Jane, Hours worked: 30, Copy generation: 0
Data: JaneCopy, Hours worked: 30, Copy generation: 1
Data: Jim, Hours worked: 20, Copy generation: 0
Data: Combined, Hours worked: 50, Copy generation: 0
Data: Jane + JaneCopy, Hours worked: 60, Copy generation: 0
Data: Testing int setter, Hours worked: 40, Copy generation: 0
Data: Testing double setter, Hours worked: 72, Copy generation: 0
```

Comment: To get a clearer understanding of the question.  You need to know when the class is copied?  Or you need to know when there is a second instance for the class for the same person for instance Jane?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is simple. your code works fine. its the compiler that you are using. do not use Visuals c++ for that case. Visual C++ does things differently. It uses the overloaded + operator as with GCC, but right afterwards, it puts the resulting object from the + operator function into the COPY CONSTRUCTOR, which then runs on the resulting object. The outcome of the copy constructor, not the outcome of the overloaded +, is what ends up in the variable named 'combined'.